# Multishipping on Prestashop 1.6.0.9

Tags: php, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, orders

Is it possible to do multishipping for orders with Prestashop 1.6.0.9 ?
If it's not include, modules exist ?

thanks !

Comment: I believe this feature was removed, I couldnt find it. It used to be available in earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

I found this module http://prestashopextensions.com/blog/multiple-shipping-addresses-in-prestashop-1-6/, but I do not work properly... but can perhaps help.

Prestashop did not disable this option entirely. The module only reactivated.

Answer (score 0):

This module has fixed. For now it work perfectly. You can see more in here.
http://prestamonster.com/en/shipping-modules/11-multi-shipping-in-prestashop-16.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.